# Razor Syntax for String

Tags: asp.net, razor

Can anyone help me with Razor equvalent code for this..

```
if (TestString.ToString().IndexOf("GRA") != -1)
{

    // code comes here..
}
```

I have problem finding the Razor equvalent for IndexOf. I need to find if a string "GRA" is present in  TestString variable.

Thanks in advance....!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@if (TestString.ToString().IndexOf("GRA") != -1)
{

    // code comes here..
}
```

As for your comment about Razor and `IndexOf` - Razor uses the whole subset of .net, so `IndexOf` can still be used in Razor pages without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
@if (TestString.ToString().IndexOf("GRA") != -1)
{
   ...
}
```